# 'this' is not defined within a backbone.js view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to implement the google maps api as a backbone.js view. This is the code I have so far for the autocomplete function:

```
    address_search_listen: function(){

    //create a new auto complete object
    var map= this.map;
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('address_search')),{types: ['geocode'] });
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed',function(){
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                    map: map,
                    title: "test"
                 });
        });
}
```

The variable map is not defined within the event handler. I have tried several things with no success. Can someone help me out?

Comment: `this` may not be referencing the View object. Try adding `_.bindAll(this, 'address_search_listen');` in initialize method of the View.

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer your question, it is better to know your backbone view structure. Specifically, where you create google map instance and where you invoke function `address_search_listen`.

If you are sure that google map instance is created and becomes a property of your `view` object, a possible reason that cause you to have undefined variable `map` is that `this` refers to other object instead of your `view` object.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above by @Manuish, use _.bind to set the scope of the handler:

```
_.bind( this, function(){
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
      map: map,
      title: "test"
  })
);
```